# Adding Multiple Vanilla JavaScript Tabs to the Same Page

Tags: javascript, tabs

Using a variation of the following code, I was able to successfully add one set of Vanilla JavaScript tabs.

Yet how to do I add multiple sets of JavaScript tabs to one page using the same classes in the HTML.

I'm having difficultly creating unique dynamic IDs for the tab selectors and tab content areas using JavaScript. As you can see in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html, these unique IDs are needed for accessible tags.

```js
var accessibleTabsContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.accessible-tabs-container');
var tabSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-selectors > li');
var tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-contents > div');
var largeRandNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);

accessibleTabsContainers.forEach(function(elem, indexAccessibleTabContainer) {
  elem.setAttribute('data-id', indexAccessibleTabContainer);
  
  tabSelector.forEach(function(singleTabSelector, i) {
   
    var ariaControlTabContent = 'tab-content-' + largeRandNumber + '-' + i + '_' + indexAccessibleTabContainer;
    var tabSelectorId = 'tab-selector-' + largeRandNumber + '-' + i + '_' + indexAccessibleTabContainer;

    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('data-id', i);
    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('id', tabSelectorId);
    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('aria-controls', ariaControlTabContent);

    tabContent[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('role', 'tabpanel');
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('id', ariaControlTabContent);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('aria-labeledby', tabSelectorId);

    if(i === 0) {
      tabSelector[i].setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
    } else {
      tabSelector[i].setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
      tabSelector[i].setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
    }
  });
});  


function onTabSelectorClick(e) {
  
  accessibleTabsContainers.forEach(function(accessibleTabsContainer, indexAccessibleTabContainer) {   
    var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;
    var accessibleTabsContainerSelected = tabSelectorSelected.parentElement.parentElement;
  
    if(!tabSelectorSelected.classList.contains('active-tab-selector')) {
      
     var tabSelectorSelectedFromContainer = accessibleTabsContainerSelected.querySelectorAll('.tab-contents > div');
      console.log(tabSelectorSelectedFromContainer);

     tabSelector.forEach(function(singleTabSelected, i) {
        if(tabSelectorSelected.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContent[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {        
           tabContent[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
        } else {
           tabSelector[i].classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
           tabSelector[i].setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
           tabSelector[i].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
           tabSelector[i].setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
           tabContent[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
        }      
      });

      tabSelectorSelected.classList.add('active-tab-selector');
      tabSelectorSelected.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');        
      tabSelectorSelected.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');
      tabSelectorSelected.removeAttribute('tabindex'); 
    }

  });
}

tabSelector.forEach(function(tabSelector) {
  tabSelector.addEventListener('click', onTabSelectorClick);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-selectors {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-selectors > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-selectors > .active-tab-selector {
  border: 1px solid #f00; 
}

.tab-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-contents > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.tab-contents > .tab-content-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Accessible Tabs using Vanilla JavaScript</h1>
  
<div class="accessible-tabs-container">  
  
 <ul role="tablist" aria-lable="Tabs Example" class="tab-selectors">
    <li class="active-tab-selector">Tab Selector 1</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 2</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 3</li>
  </ul>  

  <div class="tab-contents">
    <div class="tab-content-active">
      Tab Content 1
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 2
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 3
    </div>
  </div> 
  
  </div>
 
  
<div class="accessible-tabs-container">  
  
 <ul role="tablist" aria-lable="Tabs Example" class="tab-selectors">
    <li class="active-tab-selector">Tab Selector 1</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 2</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 3</li>
  </ul>  

  <div class="tab-contents">
    <div class="tab-content-active">
      Tab Content 1
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 2
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 3
    </div>
  </div> 

 </div>  
  
</div>
```

I'm trying to generate these unique IDs in line 6 of the Vanilla JavaScript (`accessibleTabsContainers.forEach`) but it's not working.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: @StackSlave
I'm not seeing `tabContent` as undefined. I checked the CodePen I created - https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/JjYJWjG - by doing a console log on `tabContent` and don't see that.  

Could you please create a new CodePen off of https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/JjYJWjG and which the code you changed to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue. In the `forEach` loop that iterates inside the `onTabSelectorClick` function, I refactored the code to add the lines below:

```
var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;
var accessibleTabsContainerSelected = tabSelectorSelected.closest('.accessible-tabs-container'); 
var tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs = accessibleTabsContainerSelected.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
```

Then in a `forEach` loop instead of iterating through `tabSelector` (which references `var tabSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-selectors > li');`) and loops through all tabs `li` tags, not just the ones referenced by the element clicked, I used `tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs`, which references the tab elements inside their parent `div` tag (`var accessibleTabsContainerSelected = tabSelectorSelected.closest('.accessible-tabs-container');`), from the tab element (`li` tag) clicked (`var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;`).

See https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/JjYJWjG. Also, I added the correct code in this answer. Below is a more useful before and after description of the code:

*Incorrect `forEach` Loop Snippet inside `onTabSelectorClick` function that is passed in Click Event Handler*

```
var tabSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-selectors > li');

function onTabSelectorClick(e) {
   tabSelector.forEach(function() {
     // Code here
   });
}
```

*Correct `forEach` Loop Snippet inside `onTabSelectorClick` function that is passed in Click Event Handler*

```
var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;
var accessibleTabsContainerSelected = tabSelectorSelected.closest('.accessible-tabs-container'); 
var tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs = accessibleTabsContainerSelected.querySelectorAll('ul > li');

function onTabSelectorClick(e) {
   tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs.forEach(function() {
     // Code here
   });
}
```

```js
var accessibleTabsContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.accessible-tabs-container');
var tabSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-selectors > li');
var tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-contents > div');
var largeRandNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);

accessibleTabsContainers.forEach(function(elem, indexAccessibleTabContainer) {
  elem.setAttribute('data-id', indexAccessibleTabContainer);
  
  tabSelector.forEach(function(singleTabSelector, i) {
   
    var tabSelectorId = 'tab-selector-' + largeRandNumber + '_' + i + '_' + indexAccessibleTabContainer;
    var ariaControlTabContent = 'tab-content-' + largeRandNumber + '_' + i + '_' + indexAccessibleTabContainer;

    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('data-id', i);
    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('id', tabSelectorId);
    singleTabSelector.setAttribute('aria-controls', ariaControlTabContent);

    tabContent[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('role', 'tabpanel');
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('id', ariaControlTabContent);
    tabContent[i].setAttribute('aria-labeledby', tabSelectorId);

    if(i === 0) {
      singleTabSelector.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
    } else {
      singleTabSelector.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
      singleTabSelector.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
    }
  });
});  


function onTabSelectorClick(e) {

    var tabSelectorSelected = e.target;
    var accessibleTabsContainerSelected = tabSelectorSelected.closest('.accessible-tabs-container'); 
    var tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs = accessibleTabsContainerSelected.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
    var tabContentsSelectedFromContainer = accessibleTabsContainerSelected.querySelectorAll('.tab-contents > div');
  
    if(!tabSelectorSelected.classList.contains('active-tab-selector')) {
      tabSelectorsSelectedFromTabs.forEach(function(singleTabSelected, i) {
        if(tabSelectorSelected.getAttribute('data-id') === tabContentsSelectedFromContainer[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
          singleTabSelected.classList.add('active-tab-selector');
          singleTabSelected.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
          singleTabSelected.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
          tabContentsSelectedFromContainer[i].classList.add('tab-content-active');
        } else {
          singleTabSelected.classList.remove('active-tab-selector');
          singleTabSelected.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
          singleTabSelected.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
          tabContentsSelectedFromContainer[i].classList.remove('tab-content-active');
        }

      });
    }
 
}

tabSelector.forEach(function(tabSelector) {
  tabSelector.addEventListener('click', onTabSelectorClick);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-selectors {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-selectors > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-selectors > .active-tab-selector {
  border: 1px solid #f00; 
}

.tab-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-contents > div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.tab-contents > .tab-content-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Accessible Tabs using Vanilla JavaScript</h1>
 
<div class="accessible-tabs-container">  
  
  
 <ul role="tablist" aria-lable="Tabs Example" class="tab-selectors">
    <li class="active-tab-selector">Tab Selector 1</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 2</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 3</li>
  </ul>  
  

  <div class="tab-contents">
    <div class="tab-content-active">
      Tab Content 1
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 2
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 3
    </div>
  </div> 

  </div>
  
<div class="accessible-tabs-container">  
  
  
 <ul role="tablist" aria-lable="Tabs Example" class="tab-selectors">
    <li class="active-tab-selector">Tab Selector 1</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 2</li>
    <li>Tab Selector 3</li>
  </ul>  
  

  <div class="tab-contents">
    <div class="tab-content-active">
      Tab Content 1
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 2
    </div>  
    <div>
      Tab Content 3
    </div>
  </div> 

  </div>  
  
</div>
```