# W3.org tab script not able to handle more than 1 tab component at a time

Tags: javascript, tabs

W3.org have written a nice script for accessible tabs. It all works great until more than 1 tab component is added to a page. At this point clicking a tab fires a function that loops through all `[role="tabpanel"]` on the page and adds a `hidden` attribute. The hidden attribute should only be added to tab components on an individual basis.

How do I get the function to apply to only one tab component at a time?

W3.org tab [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html) and [full script](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/js/tabs.js)

I think that this is the problem code:

```
  var tablist = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tablist"]')[0];
  var tabs;
  var panels;
  var delay = determineDelay();

  generateArrays();

  function generateArrays () {
    tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
    panels = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tabpanel"]');
  };

  // Deactivate all tabs and tab panels
  function deactivateTabs () {
    for (t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++) {
      tabs[t].setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
      tabs[t].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
      tabs[t].removeEventListener('focus', focusEventHandler);
    };

    for (p = 0; p < panels.length; p++) {
      panels[p].setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
    };
  };
```

Example of broken functionality. Note how you can see the content from both tab components initially and then after clicking any tab the content is hidden from the second tab component.

```js
function tabCount() {
  //loop through content > ul 
  $(".content ul").each(function() {
    //get length of li 
    var testLength = $(this).find("li").length
    if (testLength > 3) {
      $(this).find("li").slice(0, 3).addClass('show');
      testLength = testLength - 3;
      //hide li which doesn't have class show
      $(this).find("li:not('.show')").hide()
      //add total to button span
      $(this).closest(".content").find('.all').children('span').text(testLength);
    } else {
      $(this).find("li").addClass('show');
      $(this).closest(".content").find('.all').hide();
    }
  });
}
tabCount();


$('.all').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').show()
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 20em;
  font-family: "lucida grande", sans-serif;
}

[role="tablist"] {
  margin: 0 0 -0.1em;
  overflow: visible;
}

[role="tab"] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  background: hsl(220, 20%, 94%);
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before,
[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-radius: 0.2em 0.2em 0 0;
  border-top: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"] {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]:not(:focus):not(:hover)::before {
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(218, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"]::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0.3em;
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
  box-shadow: none;
  content: '';
}

[role="tab"]:hover,
[role="tab"]:focus,
[role="tab"]:active {
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: inherit;
}

[role="tab"]:hover::before,
[role="tab"]:focus::before {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
}

[role="tabpanel"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.7em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(219, 1%, 72%);
  background: hsl(220, 43%, 99%);
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus {
  border-color: hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  outline: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"]:focus::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid hsl(20, 96%, 48%);
  border-radius: 0 0 0.2em 0.2em;
  content: '';
}

[role="tabpanel"] p {
  margin: 0;
}

[role="tabpanel"] *+p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="nils-tab" id="nils">
      Nils Frahm
    </button>
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="agnes-tab" id="agnes" tabindex="-1">
      Agnes Obel
    </button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="nils-tab" aria-labelledby="nils" class="content">
    <ul class="publications">
      <li>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="agnes-tab" aria-labelledby="agnes" hidden="" class="content">
    <ul class="projects">
      <li>A gdfgdfg dfgdf gd.</li>
      <li>B 456465 656 periam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>C Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>D Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>E Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>F Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>G Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div role="tablist" aria-label="Entertainment">
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="nils-tab2" id="nils2">
      Nils Frahm 2
    </button>
    <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="agnes-tab2" id="agnes2" tabindex="-1">
      Agnes Obel 2
    </button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="nils-tab2" aria-labelledby="nils2" class="content">
    <ul class="publications">
      <li>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="agnes-tab2" aria-labelledby="agnes2" hidden="" class="content">
    <ul class="projects">
      <li>A gdfgdfg dfgdf gd.</li>
      <li>B 456465 656 periam, repellendus.</li>
      <li>C Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, repellendus.</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="all">Show all <span></span> peer-reviewed publications</button>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/js/tabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi , when Agnes Obel gets clicked then below tab gets closed ..you don't want that behaviour ?

Comment: Hi again @Swati. No, I don't want that behaviour. It doesn't makes sense. If either Nils Fram or Agnes Obel get clicked this should have NO effect on Nils Fram2 or Agnes Obel2 and vise versa (I should have named these better). This is the same if there are 2 or 200 different tab components on the page. I was thinking that I could wrap the function in an event handler but that's probably the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603737/adding-multiple-vanilla-javascript-tabs-to-the-same-page) post ?